# how can i fix the Java 7 Files.write error?

Tags: java, file-io, java-7, java.nio.file

my code writes to a file, I am getting access denied error while writing to the file.

```
Files.write(path, myString.getBytes());
```

The exception is as fallows

```
FAILED to write to file.
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: 
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:229)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:430)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:170)
    at java.nio.file.Files.write(Files.java:3058)
```

Comment: Looks like a permission problem writing to the file and/or directory. See [`java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/AccessDeniedException.html). You can use [`File.canWrite()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canWrite%28%29) to check if the user the code is running under has access to that part of the file system. Are you trying to create a directory on the `C` drive?

Comment: AccessDeniedException actually means that you have no permission to access the file.

Comment: whats the content of `path`? Could an other program be locking that file?

Comment: say if I wanna create a folder and save to a text file, how can i set permission?  e.g. C:\myApp\output.txt

Comment: It's a OS level setting, you can't do it from your application.

Comment: How can i set the OS level setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this is not a complete answer but it did not fit in a comment on the question. I hope it helps.

From https://superuser.com/questions/342276/cannot-save-in-hard-disk-drive-c

> Since Windows XP, the root directory of the system partition cannot be written to without administrator privileges. However, for security reasons, Windows Vista and Windows 7 do not grant administrator permissions by default even if logged on as an administrator unless explicitly elevated to this privilege level, which may require that you click through a [UAC prompt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control).

Since you are not trying to write to the root of `C:\`, I don't think it is a permission problem, so perhaps another application has a lock on the file. Did you open the `.txt` in another application (e.g. Notepad)?

One way to check open [file handles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_handle) is using [**Process Explorer**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and search for the full path or name of the file and Process Explorer will list all the processes that have an open handle to the file. You can view all the handles for any application using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and even close handles from here. Note: If you get an access denied permission when closing a handle, select *File → Show Details for all Processes* and try again.